# Cannot use factorial function in symsum

Tags: matlab

I am trying to follow this page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html

```
syms k x
S1 = symsum(k^2, k, 0, 10)
S2 = symsum(1/k^2, k, 1, Inf)
S3 = symsum(x^k/factorial(k), k, 0, Inf)
```

When I get to calculating S3, MATLAB says "Error using factorial (line 20)
N must be an array of real non-negative integers."

What am I doing wrong? I tried with the bound 1 to 10 and it gave the same error (even though the argument to factorial should be a positive integer for everything in that range).

Comment: It works for me. You will have to give more details, like Matlab version. What does `help sym/factorial` print?

Comment: Your code does not give any error in MATLAB r2016a. `S3 = exp(x)` is returned for the final calculation